# How to hide tracebacks for users when an import csv fail using django import export library

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-import-export

I have implemented successfully import and export in my app. The only thing that I can't make to work is to hide the tracebacks for users when an import fails.

I have tried so far:

`raise_errors = False` in admin.py
`.traceback{display:none}` in import.css
`DEBUG = False` in settings.py

I put wrong data starting with the column name on purpose in the csv file and I always get this per row:

```
§  Line number: 1 - "Column 'my_error' not found in dataset. Available columns are: ['column1', 'column2', 'my_err', 'column3']"

row1data1, row1data2, row1data3, 0

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\my_user\.virtualenvs\my_project-gu-pxuzP\lib\site-packages\import_export\fields.py", line 63, in clean
value = data[self.column_name]
KeyError: 'my_error'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\my_user\.virtualenvs\my_project-gu-pxuzP\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 492, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "C:\Users\my_user\.virtualenvs\my_project-gu-pxuzP\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 269, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "C:\Users\my_user\.virtualenvs\my_project-gu-pxuzP\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 263, in get_instance
return instance_loader.get_instance(row)
File "C:\Users\my_user\.virtualenvs\my_project-gu-pxuzP\lib\site-packages\import_export\instance_loaders.py", line 32, in get_instance
params[field.attribute] = field.clean(row)
File "C:\Users\my_user\.virtualenvs\my_project-gu-pxuzP\lib\site-packages\import_export\fields.py", line 66, in clean
"columns are: %s" % (self.column_name, list(data)))
KeyError: "Column 'my_erro' not found in dataset. Available columns are: ['column1', 'column2', 'my_error', 'column4']"
```

How can I get only the first lines of the message?:

```
§  Line number: 1 - "Column 'my_error' not found in dataset. Available columns are: ['column1', 'column2', 'my_err', 'column3']"

row1data1, row1data2, row1data3, 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to catch the error and print just the error, then exit, if you 
want. (assuming Python3)

```
try:
    value = data[self.column_name]
except KeyError as e:
    print("An error occurred: {}".format(e))
    # or perhaps some other action.
```

Any Exception that isn't caught and handled will produce a stack trace because it assumes that it was unintended. You want to think about what exceptions different parts of your code could generate and decide if you want to present them to the user in a different manner.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I have to think about how to override the clean method in Fields class in fields,py. I thought there was a straight forward way like `raise_errors = False`